# Checking if a given date is before current date in c# and mySql

Tags: c#, mysql, date

This is my code:

```
    string query = "UPDATE tblschedule Set Status='" + "Complete" + "'Where Date <= '"+ DateTime.Now +"';";
```

It is working if the date in the sql table is one month ahead. For example:

```
Given Date: 4/9/2017
Date Now: 3/9/2017
```

And the status will not change because it was not before the current date.

But when it is not one month ahead. For example:

```
Given Date: 3/20/2017
Date Now: 3/9/2017
```

The status will change it to complete even though it is not before the current date.

Comment: May i know type of `Date` column of `tblschedule` table.

Comment: i set it to varchar

Comment: So try my answer.It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string query = "UPDATE tblschedule Set Status='Complete' Where STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%m/%d/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('"+DateTime.Now+"','%m/%d/%Y')";
```

Try above code.Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = "UPDATE tblschedule Set Status='" + "Complete" + "'Where                     
                CAST(Date AS DATETIME) <="'+DateTime.Now+"';";
```

Note that,"Date" parameter in CAST function is the columnname